# My kivy app with firebase crashes after opnening

Tags: android, firebase, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I have a kivy app that use firebase. when I convert to apk and I run it it crashes.
I added kivymd and pillow and firebase-admin in the .spec file but it didn't work.
this is my main.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
cred = credentials.Certificate("main.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
kv = """
MDFloatLayout:
    MDLabel:#message label
        id: l
        text: ""
        font_size: 50
        adapptive_size: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .8}
        halign: "center"
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "press me to bring data"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.4}
        on_release: app.bring(l)
"""
class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    def bring(self, l):
        send = db.collection("users").document("haitham").get().to_dict()
        l.text = send["name"]

def main():
    Test().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try connecting your phone to your PC and running `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt`. Then look at the file `my_log.txt` for hints about what happened.

Comment: thanks, I solved it they said no module named google I need to add it in the requeirments